# how can I modify the generated <head> metadata?

Tags: fossil

Consider the following [documentation](https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/wiki?name=Cookbook#tinymce), it appears to be outdated.

There's no admin -> header path in fossil ui, AFAIK I have to change the source code string and recompile fossil?

Comment: Yeah this is interesting, because they're enforcing [Content-Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) more-so and I can't reference external images(imgur links and the like), which I could if I modified the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find that path either, however there is a link to both the `header` and `footer` pages from the `Skins` Admin page.

A link to `header` also shows up on the `Logo` page and links to the same location.